# Is it possible if the website is built on WordPress and landing page is built on html to link on same domain or using subdomain

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web-hosting

Is there possible if the website is built on WordPress and hosted on domain (example.com) and if I want to create one landing page which should be built with HTML/CSS but will be the host on same subdomain (example.com/example)? if yes how to do it?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In short: yes, sure. Maybe you need to adjust your webserver rewrite rules slightly, but in general: yes.

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't create a landing page template in your child theme and then create the landing page from within your wordpress site? Also, what is the intent of the landing page? A marketing campaign, splash page?

Comment: @JasonB Actually the website is very old and the theme is not scalable and other reason the client wanted the landing page should be custom built. Yes it is for marketing campaign there is no relation with their website structure just it should be link with same domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install WordPress in the example folder and it will run quite happily from there without interfering with what's in the top-level. Just have to make sure that the **WordPress Address (URL)** and **Site Address (URL)** in the **General Settings** include the folder too - ie, `http://example.com/example`

As a proof of concept, have a look at https://www.pad-fairs.com - the top-level index is a stand-alone index.php file (but could be .html - I just use php to change the date order of the links) and each of the 3 sub sites are separate installs of WordPress in their own folders.

Hope that helps